# a ref class can only inherit from a ref class or interface class

Tags: c++, c++-cx

Working on a C++/CX project, that makes use of C++ code I need to inherit from the C++ layer but keep getting this error:

> a ref class can only inherit from a ref class or interface class

is there a way that I can go around it, from looking around the internet I found that it is not possible to do a direct inheritance, the code is like this:

C++ code

> Class A

C++/CX

> public ref Class B : public A

that is not possible, do you know of a way that I can achieve the same "result" through different design

also if i make a C++ class in the C++/CX project I am not allowed to set it as public

Comment: Why do you need to inherit from the C++ layer? Depending on the reasons (i.e. how you want to use the classes), the possible solutions will differ. So please give us bit more insight.

Comment: dont worry managed to fix it, just used it as private then pushed what i needed up

Comment: It is pretty fundamental, a *ref class* is a COM wrapper.  COM does not support implementation inheritance.  One of the bigger reasons it is so universally applicable.  You'll need to fall back to encapsulation.  You'll probably end up with a whole bunch of little methods that do nothing but forward the call to the encapsulated C++ class.

Comment: That is what i ended up doing, thanks for the help !! was still hoping there is another way, that is not process intensive, if you think of a way that decrease the number of encapsulation methods leave a comment :) Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

And what about to use `interface` instead of pure `class`:

```
public interface class A
{
};

public ref class B : public A
{
};
```

More details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/interfaces-c-cx).